# Linux: Setting primary display (nvidia) from command line

Tags: linux, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, twinview

Is this possible?

Normally I use `disper` to enable my external monitor, but I don't think I can force the 2nd monitor to be primary.
http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/

I've played around with `nv-control-dpy` included in the nvidia-control source, but I haven't figured out how to do it yet. How to get:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=922956

#### EDIT

This is a laptop, to which I connect an external hdmi display when I get to work. `dipser -e` extends the desktop for me, but the laptop remains the primary desktop (holding the panels etc). `nvidia-settings` can set primary monitor for me, but I want to use the cli.

Comment: what's the hardware here?  laptop with external monitor?  two monitors connected to one GPU?  two GPUs?

Comment: nvidia binary drivers...enough said. This would probably be really easy with xrandr, but the nvidia drivers only support their proprietary twinview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I succeed to exactly do what you mean, maybe because I have the 2.3 version, on ubuntu 10.04 with nvidia-setting v 1.0

---

#### Following The Bug Fix:

this has been listed as a big once :

https://bugs.launchpad.net/disper/+bug/321288

by version 2.1 should work as you asked on 20010-04 and the 'bug fix' was confirmed on 2009-02-16

#### What I Had

by using:

```
disper -l
```

there I saw my devices were:

- DFP-0: LGD                 (laptop display)
- CRT-0: Samsung SyncMaster  (external monitor)

(the external device doesn't show up by querying with xrandr)

#### What I Wanted and How

The **laptop is on the right** and the **monitor is on the left**, i wanted the laptop to be extended **from** the Samsung, thus, having the laptop physically top aligned, I wanted them to be also logically top aligned and have theyr own maxymum resolution:

```
disper -d CRT-0,DFP-0 -r auto -e -t right
```

this has to be read as: (*-d*) opertate first on SyncMaster then on laptop lcd, (*-r*) consider auto resolution, (*-e*) extend the second dysplay [second here is laptop because the *-d* set display ordering], (*-t*) extend the second display [laptop] to the right of the first.

#### Google Properly and Try First

Very Simple no nvidia-hacking needed. Hope it helps.

---

Cheers

Splinux

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks :) v 2.3 did exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I hacked the nvidia-settings source, and got a working solution:

This is done in Ubuntu, but porting it shouldn't be hard.

Run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nvidia-settings
apt-get source nvidia-settings
cd nvidia-settings-195.36.08/src
```

Edit "nvidia-settings.c", and replace main() with this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{


    ConfigProperties conf;
    ParsedAttribute *p; 
    CtrlHandles *h; 
    char * target;

    /* initialize the parsed attribute list */

    p = nv_parsed_attribute_init();

    /* initialize the ConfigProperties */

    init_config_properties(&conf);

    /* allocate the CtrlHandles for this X screen */

    h = nv_alloc_ctrl_handles(":0.0");

    if (!h || !h->dpy) {
        return 1;
    }   

    /* Get target from command line */
    if(argc != 2){ 
            printf("Usage: %s PRIMARY_DISPLAY\n", argv[0]);
        printf("Example: %s  DFP-1\n");
        return 1;
    }   

    target = argv[1];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < h->targets[X_SCREEN_TARGET].n; i++) {
        if (h->targets[X_SCREEN_TARGET].t[i].h) {

            printf("Setting primary display: %s\n", target);

            NvCtrlSetStringAttribute(h->targets[X_SCREEN_TARGET].t[i].h, NV_CTRL_STRING_TWINVIEW_XINERAMA_INFO_ORDER, target, NULL);

            break;
        }   
    }   

    return 0;

} /* main() */
```

compile:

```
cd ..
make
```

put the binary in path:

```
sudo cp nvidia-settings /usr/local/bin/setPrimaryDisplay
```

use it:

```
setPrimaryDisplay DFP-1
gnome-panel --replace 2>/dev/null &
```

Where DFP-1 is the name of the desired diaplay display. Gnome panel doesn't keep up with the times, and needs to be restarted.

You can download my binary compiled for amd64 here: http://while1.no/files/setPrimaryDisplay

Answer (score 0):

May be too obvious and an option you prefer not to use, but, what about changing which is the primary one at BIOS ?

Comment: The external is only connected about half the times i boot, so that'd be more work than using nvidia-settins gui. In fact, I never actually boot this computer, its just suspended.

Answer (score 0):

You can try messing with `xrandr`. commandlinefu have great [collection](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/matching/xrandr/eHJhbmRy/sort-by-votes) of xrandr-based scripts.