# Linux VGA Monitor plug-in on demand with NVIDIA is never detected

Tags: xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, xrandr, twinview

Whenever I plug in an LCD LG monitor via VGA to my notebook while running X it never gets detected.

As a matter of a fact there are only two scenarios that occur:

1. X server is started with monitor already plugged in: xrandr shows one display with resolution equal to the sum of both displays (something like 3000x1080), however, I can use the monitor at will,
2. X server is started without monitor plugged in: xrandr shows only my notebook display (1280x900) and the appropriate resolution.

Even though I can use the monitor at this very moment, it requires X restart in order to start with new resolution. What is more in both cases the monitor is never shown as a another display/screen in xrandr, it only makes the only display entry resolution in xrandr bigger.  That might not be that serious, but whenever I want to use the monitor after I have started X - it doesn't even get detected.

From what I can gather that is a problem of NVIDIA drivers and me using NVIDIA's TwinView, as you can see in the attached xorg.conf.

Do you think the problem could be resolved while using NVIDIA drivers or is it a complication due to the usage of TwinView?

I am running Gentoo Linux, tuxonice-sources package version **2.6.38**-tuxonice-r2

- **my xorg.conf:** http://openpaste.org/0C753b7f
- **xorg-server version:** 1.10.2
- **xorg-drivers version:** 1.11 (latest)

Comment: Solved, see above.

Comment: @slhck: Oh, right. I am sorry for that. I have tried to make a new post, however, because of my beginner status here on this server I cannot post a reply for another few hours, by editing the post I was hoping to avoid unnecessary replies. I shall wait the time alloted then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Linux: Setting primary display (nvidia) from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/131192/linux-setting-primary-display-nvidia-form-command-line)

I used [the disper 0.3.0 package](http://ppa.launchpad.net/disper-dev/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/d/disper/disper_0.3.0.tar.gz) ([homepage](http://willem.engen.nl/projects/disper/)) and then used

```
./disper.py -d DFP-0,CRT-0 -r auto -e -t right
```

and the result was exactly as required.

Answer (score 1):

> Whenever I plug in an LCD LG monitor via VGA to my notebook while running X it never gets detected.

if it is *plugged*, enter

```
$ xranddr
```

It will list out the connected/disconnected outputs:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2340 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 303mm x 190mm
   1440x900       60.0*+   50.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       59.9  
   800x600        59.9  
   640x480        59.4  
   720x400        59.6  
   640x400        60.0  
   640x350        59.8  
VGA-1 connected 900x1440+1440+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 408mm x 255mm
   1440x900       59.9*+   75.0  
   1280x1024      76.0     75.0     72.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3  
   640x480        72.8     75.0     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
   640x350        70.1  
DVI-D-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```